# Dynamic menu according to user on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm developing a manual access control on Rails and need some help with dynamic menus.

I have 3 models: User, Group and Functionality

User has one group

Group has many users

Groups has many functionalities

Users has many functionalities through Groups.

K. Now, when I login with 'admin' I want to render a dynamic menu with Administrator's group functionalities.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of this as a Helper

```
def admin_content(current_user)
  if current_user.admin?
    render 'partial'
  end
end
```

You can then call it in your view.

Comment: but how I will generate dynamic menu? If I need to render a partial, will be static, right?

Comment: Partial can be as dynamic as the content you put in it!  All the method I outlined above does is choose where to render to content or not.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) that "is an authorization library for Ruby on Rails which restricts what resources a given user is allowed to access."

You can then use an `initialize` method like they give on the [example](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities) to have a better control over your menu.

```
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
```

Comment: and how can i link Menu option to a specific link, dynamically?

Comment: @GuilhermeCarlos, please define "dynamic menu". What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: according to user's group, render menu with it functionalities. eg: Admin group have Create User functionality. When i login with admin user (who is in Admin group) in my main menu will appear 'Create User'. If I add any other functionality to this group, it will appear on menu too

Comment: After you have the roles setup with [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) you can just use something like @muttonlamb suggested to separate the menus for users and admins.

Comment: I think I didn't explain very well. I need to know how to turn on the 'Create User' with the link / user / new without having a fixed code